# libmagic thinks docx is application/octet-stream

Tags: ubuntu, files

On my Ubuntu 18 workstation when I check the mime type for a Word docx file I get the following:

```
$ file --mime src/tests/data_sources/test_data/word.docx
src/tests/data_sources/test_data/word.docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary
```

Perfect, however if I start an 'ubuntu:18.04' docker container on my gitlab CI instance I get the following:

```
$ file --mime src/tests/data_sources/test_data/word.docx
src/tests/data_sources/test_data/word.docx: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

What could be the reason for this? And any ideas how to fix it? On both systems I'm just cloning a git repo containing this file then running the above command.

Thanks in advance